# array collection filter flex

Tags: apache-flex, arraycollection, filterfunction

hey guys, is it possible for me to filter only a certain column in a arraycollection but still displaying the other values in a datagrid?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Are you saying that you want to display the values that were filtered out of the collection in a separate component?

Answer (score 0):

yes it can be done by label function